# 400 GB tar.gz file upload from ec2 to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have an ec2 instance where a approx. 400 GB file (tar.gz) is stored.

I now want to unzip and upload that file and store it inside a s3 bucket which is in the same aws account.

Regarding the normal aws s3 cp command i always ran into timeouts.

What is the easiest way to accomplish that task

Comment: Can you tell us more about the timeouts you have been experiencing? Is this when using `aws s3 cp` to upload from EC2 to S3? Is the EC2 instance in the same region as the S3 bucket? What timed out -- the upload or your SSH connection? More info, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They sync should possibly work. In general, the underlying mechanics is probably built on multi-part upload. That may be useful to know if you want to implement it yourself. It can be done even from command line.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpu-upload-object.html

The process may look intimidating, but it is not that bad and the benefit is that you can **upload a large file even over a bad line**, because you **can re-try individual parts**. You can also **finish the upload later** - for example after your temporary permissions do expire or the next day. Or possibly you **can upload from two locations** as long as the file is split the exact same way.

Initiate the upload:

```
aws s3api create-multipart-upload --bucket my-bucket --key 'multipart/01'
{
    "Bucket": "my-bucket",
    "UploadId": "dfRtDYU0WWCCcH43C3WFbkRONycyCpTJJvxu2i5GYkZljF.Yxwh6XG7WfS2vC4to6HiV6Yjlx.cph0gtNBtJ8P3URCSbB7rjxI5iEwVDmgaXZOGgkk5nVTW16HOQ5l0R",
    "Key": "multipart/01"
}
```

Upload part:

```
aws s3api upload-part --bucket my-bucket --key 'multipart/01' --part-number 1 --body part01 --upload-id  "dfRtDYU0WWCCcH43C3WFbkRONycyCpTJJvxu2i5GYkZljF.Yxwh6XG7WfS2vC4to6HiV6Yjlx.cph0gtNBtJ8P3URCSbB7rjxI5iEwVDmgaXZOGgkk5nVTW16HOQ5l0R"
```

Complete multi-part:

```
aws s3api complete-multipart-upload --multipart-upload file://mpustruct --bucket my-bucket --key 'multipart/01' --upload-id dfRtDYU0WWCCcH43C3WFbkRONycyCpTJJvxu2i5GYkZljF.Yxwh6XG7WfS2vC4to6HiV6Yjlx.cph0gtNBtJ8P3URCSbB7rjxI5iEwVDmgaXZOGgkk5nVTW16HOQ5l0R
```

The mpstruct is:

```
{
  "Parts": [
    {
      "ETag": "e868e0f4719e394144ef36531ee6824c",
      "PartNumber": 1
    },
    {
      "ETag": "6bb2b12753d66fe86da4998aa33fffb0",
      "PartNumber": 2
    },
    {
      "ETag": "d0a0112e841abec9c9ec83406f0159c8",
      "PartNumber": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

the structure can be obtained also from the `list-multipart-uploads` command.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `s3 sync` instead of `s3 cp`.

```
aws s3 --region us-east-1 sync [folder] s3://[bucketname]
```